# Showing that $\log (\log 1+\frac{1}{|x|})$ belongs to $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for $p \geq 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I want to show that the function $f$ belongs to $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $p \geq 2$, where $f$ is defined as $$ f(x)=\log\left(\log \left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right) \right)$$

Note: This is an example of a function that is not in $L^{\infty}$, I want it as an example of a function that belongs to $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but not to $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Do you know what you should be doing to show this function belongs to such space...?

Comment: Mmm, I should check that $f$ has weak derivatives and that they are in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $p  \geq 2$, right? Maybe there is another trick...

Comment: @D1X: What do you think? What is the classical derivative?